# How to pass parameters in constructor of inherited class program?

Tags: c#, .net, class, constructor

this is my code what is the error ?
and how to solve it.
As discussed, constructor is a method and it won’t contain any return type. If we want to create a constructor in c#, then we need to create a method whose name is same as the class name.

```
class Program
    {
        public static int number;
        public static string name;
        public static float salary = 20000;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Welcome");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Your Name: ");
            name = Console.ReadLine();
            Employee System = new Employee("Sameed", 20000f);
            Bonus b1 = new Bonus();
            //b1.Employee(name, salary);
            b1.Salary(salary);
            b1.Bonuses();
            Display(number);
            Display(name,number);
    }
    static void Display(int n)
{

    Console.WriteLine("Employee Number is: " +n);
}
    static void Display(string name, int num)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Congratulations {0}, your Employee number has been generated {1}",name,num);
}
}
public class Employee
{
    public Employee(string n, float s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello Mr. {0}, Your Salary is {1}", n, s);
    }
}
public class Director:Employee
{
    public void Salary(float s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your Salary is: " + s);
    }
}
    public class Bonus:Director
    {
        public void Bonuses()
        {

            int bonus = 40000;
            Console.WriteLine("Your Bonus is: " + bonus);
        }
    }
```

Error:  Employee' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Comment: The class director needs to have a constructor that you write. This constructor needs to call base(n,s) which is the constructor for employee. You can either pass parameters from the director constructor through to base, or you could provide hard coded values to base. Whichever meets your need at getting the right data to the employee constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Since `Director` class inherits `Employee` class, it should use the constructor of base class to create an actual instance. So, in your code you add constructor to `Director` class as well and call the base class constructor, like that

```cs
public Director(string n, float s) : base(n, s)
{
}
```

Without this compiler generate your an error

> error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the
>   required formal parameter

The same should be done for `Bonus` class

```cs
public Bonus(string n, float s) : base(n, s)
{
}
```

The `Bonus` instance creation will be the following

```
Bonus b1 = new Bonus(name, salary);
```

Have a look at [instance constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/instance-constructors) and [using constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-constructors) articles. The sample in a second article is very close to OP code

Comment: @Sohaib Riaz Does it answer your question, do you need more information?

Answer (score 0):

So, your `Director` is an `Employee`. And an `Employee` can only be instantiated with 2 values - `name` and `salary`. Therefore, because your `Director` is an `Employee` that means the same rule applies to him - he *has* to have a name and a salary.

The fix is to call the `base` constructor on `Director` - i.e. call the `Employee` constructor.

"How do I do that?" I hear you ask. Well, with the special `base` call:

```
public class Employee
{
    public Employee(string n, float s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello Mr. {0}, Your Salary is {1}", n, s);
    }
}

public class Director : Employee
{
    public void Salary(string name, float salary)
        : base(name, salary) // Make sure you include this line
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your Salary is: " + s);
    }
}
```

### But wait, there's more!

I'd also like to make a few suggestions regarding your code.

1) Please use longer variable names: `name` and `salary` are *much* clearer than `n` and `s`.

2) You are inheriting `Bonus` from `Director`. Inheritance is an `is-a` relationship. So, stating "Director is an Employee" makes complete sense, but stating "Bonus is a Director` doesn't (unless you are using "Bonus" in a very unusual sense). If you can't say something is-a something else, then inheritance is not the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

Any inherited class constructor must pass required params to the base.
Thus the public Director : base (required values here).
If you don't want to pass values to the Director constructor, you can do that.
However, you must still pass something to the base class.
For example:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var bob = new Director("Bob");
        Console.WriteLine(bob.Salary);

    }
}

public class Employee
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public float Salary {get;set;}

    public Employee(string name, float salary)
    {
        Name = name;
        Salary = salary;
    }
}

public class Director : Employee
{
    public Director(string name) : base (name, 250000)
    {

    }
}
```

As previous answers stated, it's best to use more descriptive variables and it doesn't make sense to inherit Employee/Director to Bonus. An Employee has-a Bonus. Granted, I consider some employees to be a bonus :)